# Kubernetes UI dashboard

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to configure the Kubernetes UI dashboard. with full admin permissions, so created a YAML file: `dashboard-admin.yaml`.
contents of my file are below:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1.12.1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding   
metadata:   
    name: kubernetes-dashboard
    labels:
      k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
roleRef:        
   apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
   kind: ClusterRole    
   name: cluster-admin    
subjects:    
 kind: ServiceAccount      
 name: kubernetes-dashboard    
 namespace: kube-system
```

so when I am trying to apply changes to this file by executing the command
`kubectl create -f dashboard-admin.yaml`

1) I'm encountering with an error as stated below:

```
error: error parsing dashboard-admin.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 12: mapping values are not allowed in this context
```

2) Also, after running the `kubectl proxy` command, I'm unable to open the dashboard in my local machine using the link below:

```
http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/
```

Comment: Use http://www.yamllint.com/ or something similar to validate the yaml, till you get comfortable.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is related to YAML indentation. I've edited the question that shows the correct format. Or if you'd like you can use this one too.

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1.12.1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding   
metadata:   
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  labels:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
roleRef:        
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole    
  name: cluster-admin    
subjects:    
- kind: ServiceAccount      
  name: kubernetes-dashboard    
  namespace: kube-system
```

Your K8s dashboard will not work unless you have correctly setup the RBAC rule above,

Comment: after making the necessary indentation changes , i got new error :  error: unable to recognize "dashboard-admin.yaml": no matches for kind "ClusterR                                                                                                             oleBinding" in version "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1.12.1"

Comment: You have a whitespace in `ClusterR oleBinding`

Comment: theres no space i checked, while copying it , it appeared such

Comment: You are also missing a `-` under `subjects` before `kind:`. That's an array. Updated the answer

Comment: i have updated it, but still theres an error: error parsing dashboard-admin.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 8: did not find expected key. LINE 8 : apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io